# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch | Django is working fine until I created custom signup page. In that specific page, django raises url tag error

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm building my custom signup page using built-in django authentication. For some reason, my navbar is raising error that it can't read

```
<li><a href="{% url 'jobs:job_list' %}">Browse Job</a></li>
```

and that NoReverseMatch, knowingly that django only throws this error on that particular signup page.

Other pages, this url tag is being read by django and it is working completely fine.

I tried to delete the HTML page, nothing working. I'm looking for a solution in which my signup page get rendered successfully without being stopped by the NoReverseMatch error while reading my navbar url tag successfully.

```
<li><a href="{% url 'jobs:job_list' %}">Browse Job</a></li>
```

==============
project/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('jobs/', include('jobs.urls', namespace='jobs')),
    path('contact', include('contact.urls', namespace='contact')),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
    path('', include('home.urls', namespace='home')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

accounts/urls.py

```
from django.urls import  path

from . import views

app_name = 'jobs'

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup', views.sign_up, name='sign_up'),
]
```

accounts/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import SignupForm


# Create your views here.


def sign_up(request):
    # If method is post, save data and send request
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
    else:  # just display form
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: please provide urls.py

Comment: please provide also the jobs.url ... I can already spot a `app_name = "jobs"` inside the accounts.url which seems wrong

Comment: Yes, problem solved after i changed the app_name from "jobs" to "accounts". This explains why django couldn't read that particular page. It was because it was reading the accounts app before the jobs app, so it couldn't get to the jobs:job_list URL tag.